# How to solve PCL linking errors?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, point-cloud-library, kdtree, pcl

EDIT: Updated code

I'm using PCL library to generate a mesh from point clouds. This is the code, based on the Greedy Triangulation tutorial in the PCL docs:

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/common/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/search/kdtree.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/surface/gp3.h>
#include <pcl/io/obj_io.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud1;
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud2;
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud3;

    pcl::io::loadPLYFile("../cam_1_2.ply", cloud1);
    pcl::io::loadPLYFile("../cam_2_3.ply", cloud2);
    pcl::io::loadPLYFile("../cam_3_4.ply", cloud3);

    cloud1 += cloud2 + cloud3;

    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(cloud1, *cloud);

    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> n;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    tree->setInputCloud(cloud);
    n.setInputCloud(cloud);
    n.setSearchMethod(tree);
    n.setKSearch(20);
    n.compute(*normals);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloudWithNormals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
    pcl::concatenateFields(*cloud, *normals, *cloudWithNormals);

    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr tree2 (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>);
    tree2->setInputCloud (cloudWithNormals);

    pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation<pcl::PointNormal> gp3;
    pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;

    gp3.setSearchRadius(0.025);

    gp3.setMu(2.5);
    gp3.setMaximumNearestNeighbors(100);
    gp3.setMaximumSurfaceAngle(M_PI/4);
    gp3.setMinimumAngle(M_PI/18);
    gp3.setMaximumAngle(2 * M_PI / 3);
    gp3.setNormalConsistency(false);

    gp3.setInputCloud(cloudWithNormals);
    gp3.setSearchMethod(tree2);
    gp3.reconstruct(triangles);

    std::vector<int> parts = gp3.getPartIDs();
    std::vector<int> states = gp3.getPointStates();

    pcl::io::saveOBJFile("../cam_1_2.obj", triangles);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the CMakeLists file i'm using to build this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TestProject)

find_package(PCL 1.12 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test ${PCL_LIBRARIES} liblz4.so libpthread.so)
```

This is the make output in terminal:

```
 make                                                                                                                                                                              2 ↵
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target Test
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> > >::KdTree(bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEC2Eb[_ZN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEC5Eb]+0x5e): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::Search(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>::OrganizedNeighbor(bool, float, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEC2Ebfj[_ZN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEC5Ebfj]+0x66): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::Search(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::setSortedResults(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::getSortedResults()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x50): undefined reference to `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointXYZ const&, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x58): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x60): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(int, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x68): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, int, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x70): undefined reference to `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointXYZ const&, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x78): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x80): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x88): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, double, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::getSortedResults()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x58): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x60): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(int, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x68): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, int, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x78): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x80): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZENS_11KdTreeFLANNIS2_N5flann9L2_SimpleIfEEEEEE]+0x88): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, double, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::setSortedResults(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::getSortedResults()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x58): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x60): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(int, int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x68): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, int, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x78): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x80): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(int, double, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x88): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search<pcl::PointXYZ>::radiusSearch(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, double, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >&, unsigned int) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEE13setInputCloudERKSt10shared_ptrIKNS_10PointCloudIS2_EEERKS4_IKSt6vectorIiSaIiEEE[_ZN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEE13setInputCloudERKSt10shared_ptrIKNS_10PointCloudIS2_EEERKS4_IKSt6vectorIiSaIiEEE]+0x1ea): undefined reference to `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>::estimateProjectionMatrix()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:154: Test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I have found a few related issues people have encountered similar to this and I have tried all the solutions provided without any help.

I am building this on Arch linux 1.4, PCL versuin 1.12.1

EDIT: Following is the output of `make -j6 VERBOSE=1`

```
❯ make -j6 VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh -B/home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build/CMakeFiles /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build'
cd /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build/CMakeFiles/Test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
/opt/cuda/bin/g++ -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_ATOMIC_NO_LIB -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_NO_LIB -DBOOST_SERIALIZATION_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SERIALIZATION_NO_LIB -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB -DDISABLE_PCAP -DDISABLE_PNG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -Dkiss_fft_scalar=double -isystem /usr/include/pcl-1.12 -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -isystem /usr/include/ni -isystem /usr/include/openni2 -isystem /usr/include/vtk -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/qt -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtOpenGL -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -msse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -march=native -mavx2 -pthread -fopenmp -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/beany/Documents/projects/pc2mesh/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/cuda/bin/g++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -o Test  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/openmpi /usr/lib/libpcl_io.so -lOpenNI /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so -lOpenNI2 /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so /usr/lib/libvtkChartsCore.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkInteractionImage.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkIOGeometry.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkIOPLY.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingLOD.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkViewsContext2D.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkGUISupportQt.so.9.1.0 -llz4 -lpthread /usr/lib/libpcl_octree.so /usr/lib/libpcl_common.so /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.78.0 /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.78.0 /usr/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.78.0 /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.78.0 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.78.0 /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.78.0 /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so /usr/lib/libvtkViewsCore.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkInteractionWidgets.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltersModeling.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkInteractionStyle.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltersExtraction.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkIOLegacy.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkIOCore.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingAnnotation.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingContext2D.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingFreeType.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/libvtkImagingSources.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkIOImage.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkImagingCore.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingUI.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkRenderingCore.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonColor.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltersGeometry.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltersSources.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltersGeneral.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkFiltersCore.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonExecutionModel.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonDataModel.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonMisc.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonTransforms.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonMath.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libvtkkissfft.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so /usr/lib/libX11.so /usr/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.15.2 /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.2 /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.15.2 /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.2 /usr/lib/libvtkCommonCore.so.9.1.0 -pthread /usr/lib/libtbb.so.12.5 -lgomp -lpthread /usr/lib/libvtksys.so.9.1.0 -ldl -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib/openmpi
```

Comment: Please, run `make VERBOSE=1` so that we can see the actual commands that are building the project. Perhaps we might be able to see what linkage flag is missing.

Comment: @llualpu I am posting the output of make VERBOSE=1

Comment: What I can see in the output (please, next time do not execute it with `-j`) is that you are missing some library in `target_link_libraries` in your CMake (as you knew, probably). Try to find the `.so` file containing `pcl` and `search` in the name. Then add that library to the `target_link_libraries`. I'm sorry I can't help you much more.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the code in https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/greedy_projection.html#greedy-triangulation, I copied and pasted the code .cpp and the CMakeList.txt explained on the tutorial and that one is working fine for me.

Taking a look on the diffs from your code I discovered when I compile without the "common io" in find_package its compiling without problems.I'm using PCL 1.2 and ubuntu 20.04.

In my case, the changes in CMakeList is like:
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS)

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted above by @Junior solved my problem as well. Simply remove the "common io" from find_package. By refering to https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/greedy_projection.

Working CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TestProject)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Failed to compile CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TestProject)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED common io)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

If all else fails, reinstall it https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/4790#issuecomment-855379558

*Uninstall*

- [how to uninstall libpcl](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/libpcl-dev?type=uninstall)!
- `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libpcl-dev`

*Reinstall*

- [pcl download link](https://pointclouds.org/downloads/)
- `sudo apt install libpcl-dev`

Answer (score -1):

Adding the `search` module to the list of required components in `find_package` should solve the linking errors. You are using classes from that module, after all.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer: please say why you did. Was it not understandable? Does it not solve the problem? If I know the reason, maybe I can improve my answer.